# How to double quote a wildcard pattern of files?

Tags: bash, quoting, wildcards

I've seen a bunch of similar questions to this one but none exactly the same.

I have a directory of files which I want to pass in as a single, double-quoted argument to a command, using wildcard expansion.

**Files**

```
a.ext
b.ext
c.ext
```

**Desired Use**

```bsh
command --flag "a.ext b.ext c.ext"
```

Currently, I'm using `command --flag $(echo \"$(echo ./*.ext)\")`, but that doesn't work and also seems unnecessarily complex. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "using wildcard expansion"? Can you give an example of using it, and what it should do? BTW, passing filenames in a single space-delimited string is generally a bad idea, because filenames can *contain* spaces.

Comment: The command I gave is the example, specifically `./*.ext`. In this case I'm ok with a space delimited string since I am generating all of the filenames myself.

Comment: Are you trying to turn a wildcard pattern into a space-separated list of matching filenames? If so, is it a fixed pattern (i.e. *always* `./*.ext`), or in a variable or parameter or something? Also, note that `./*.ext` would expand to something like `./a.ext ./b.ext ./c.ext` (i.e. since `./` is specified as part of the pattern, it'll also appear in the result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to join the filenames resulting of the expansion of a glob with SPC characters, you can store them in the positional parameters and use `"$*"` to do the joining:

```
set -- ./*.ext
IFS=' ' # SPC is the first character of $IFS by default, we're setting it
        # here in case that code is called in a context where it has been
        # modified before.
files_joined_with_SPC="$*"
cmd --flag "$files_joined_with_SPC"
```

Or:

```
cmd --flag "$*"
```

directly of course (though it's easier to lose track of the fact that it depends on the current value of `$IFS`).

The above is standard POSIX `sh` syntax. In `zsh`/`ksh93`/`bash`/`mksh`/`yash`, you can also use an array in place of the positional parameters:

```
files=(./*.ext)
IFS=' '; files_joined_with_SPC="${files[*]}"
```

With `zsh`, you can also use:

```
files=(./*.ext)
cmd --flag "${(j[ ])files}"
```

Or using an anonymous function:

```
(){ cmd --flag "${(j[ ])argv}"; } ./*.ext
```

Where we explicitly request the `j`oining with SPC without having to rely on a global parameter like `$IFS`.

Now, note that SPC is as valid  a character as any in a file path. Any character but NUL is valid in a file path (actually any *byte value* but 0 on most systems, those bytes don't even have to form valid characters), but NUL cannot be passed in an argument to a command that is *executed*.

You don't say what that *`command`* is (by the way `command` is the name of a standard shell builtin command, I prefer to use `cmd` for a placeholder), but if that `cmd --flag list` is meant to accept any list of file name, SPC delimited, they must have a way to let users specify a `SPC` in the file name.

That could be `cmd --flag 'with\ space.ext other.ext'` or `cmd --flag 'with%20space.ext other.ext`, `cmd --flag 'with\040space.ext other.ext'`, etc.

In which case, when building that argument to `cmd --flag`, you may have to *escape* that SPC (and possibly `\` or `%` characters) in file names before joining them with SPC.

In `ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash`/`yash`, that could be done with:

```
escaped_files=("${files[@]//\\/\\\\}") # \ escaped as \\
escaped_files=("{files[@]// /\\ }")    # SPC escaped as \SPC
# more characters may need to be escaped such as other whitespace
# or quoting characters, depending on the exact syntax expected by
# cmd for the --flag option.

IFS=' '; escaped_files_joined_with_SPC="$*"
cmd -- flag "$escaped_files_joined_with_SPC"
```

(though beware of locales that use a character encoding such as GB18030, BIG5... where some characters contain the encoding of backslash (byte 0x5c). Your shell may not escape those 0x5c byte but `cmd --flag` might still consider  them as backslash if it's not decoding the arguments as per the locale's charset).

More reliable/convenient ways for commands to get a *list* of file names is to just take them as separate arguments (so not as arguments to an option), or as `cmd --flag 'file 1.ext' --flag 'file 2.ext'...`.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the filenames in one quoted string:

```
command --flag "$(echo ./*.ext)"
```

As you know, this only works for simple filenames.  This means no whitespace in the file names.  Depending on the value of `xpg_echo`, it may also mean no backslashes (hat tip: [kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)).

Comment: Depending on whether the `xpg_echo` shell option is set or not, names containing backslashes may also be modified by the act of using `echo` to output them.

Comment: @Kusalananda Very good point.  Answer updated to mention `xpg_echo`.

Comment: And as usual with `echo`, you need to make sure the pattern doesn't match files like `-n`, `-e`, `-Enen`..., and as usual with command substitution, newline characters at the end of filenames would also be a problem.

Comment: consider using printf instead of echo to avoid such issues.

Comment: @pLumo. `"$(printf '%s ' *)"` would address both the `echo` and command substitution issues, but as that would end in a SPC character, there's the question of whether `command --flag` would  consider `"file "` as one `"file"` file, or the `"file"` and `""` files separated by a SPC.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  In the comments, the OP wrote "I'm ok with a space delimited string since I am generating all of the filenames myself."  If the OP were to consider filenames with spaces, then the whole space-separated list approach would, of course, need to changed.  Since each filename starts with `./` and, under the OP's premise, has no spaces, it is not clear to me how echo's `-n` or other options could be invoked.

Comment: Yes, but it's a Q&A that could be useful to not just the OP, so it's a good idea to point out the limitations in any case, even if they don't apply in the specific use case of the OP.

Comment: This actually solved my problem, so I'm using it, but I accepted the other answer as it goes much more in-depth into the _general_ solution.

Answer (score 1):

setup a for loop of the glob expanded files.
Let the shell variable named var be the container for the filenames. In every iteration we update the shell variable var

```
var=
for f in *.ext; do var=${var-}${var:+ }$f; done
your_command --flag "$var"
```